# Joomla Blog/Wordpress Integration

Tags: wordpress, joomla

I'm looking for a wordpress-like blog interface to put inside a Joomla hosted site.  The admin interface of Joomla is quirky enough and hard enough to use that daily updates are infeasible.

What I am looking for is an easy-to-use posting interface that supports multiple users with different accounts/names, a tagging scheme, and easy find by date/user/tag functionality.

In particular I'm looking for a relatively easy-to-deploy, out-of-the-box solution, and would prefer not to hack rss feeds together or write too much custom code.  I know there are [several extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/component/option,com_mtree/task,listcats/cat_id,1759/Itemid,35/) out there but they all receive largely mixed reviews... Has anyone used any of these?  Or has anyone had experience putting something like this together?

Answer (score 2):

Well you could do this - have a wordpress installation. Get the users to post there and then use the RSS feed from it (or the XML RPC Blogging API) to update the Joomla installation. You will have to write the update piece once, but then all the headache is gone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not trying to be smart here, but if the admin interface of Joomla isn't working for you, aren't you doing yourself a disservice by trying to patch their UI instead of spending your time looking for a CMS that is easier to manage/a better fit for your user base?

**Edit:** All of the CMS's I've dealt with in ASP.NET are homegrown. However I'm looking into checking out [Umbraco](http://www.umbraco.org/) based on the recommendations of two well-respected friends. In the case you presented where you already have content in Joomla and a migration out to another CMS is going to be overkill, I think that vaibhav has got it right. You should look into setting up Wordpress or some other blogging engine and then simply have Joomla consume the content and display it in the Joomla site. I've not done it, but from what I remember of Joomla when I was looking at it, I believe that it would support this.

Comment: Perhaps, although Joomla isn't specifically designed for blogging and really doesn't support quick content pushes the way something like wordpress does.  Also there is an existing site in Joomla that I want to add a blog to, so there is a non-trivial cost of switching. Are you offering a better CMS?

Answer (score 0):

After doing a bit more research I decided to go with the open source [MojoBlog](http://www.joomlify.com/).  It was quite easy to install and configure and after a few stalls and hang ups that were resolved via perusal of their forums I was up and running.  The edit interface is not ideal but it much better than Joomla admin, and it has multi-user-support, tag categorization, modules for viewing by tag, date, etc.  Think it will suffice for my needs in the short term.

Answer (score 0):

We at 'corePHP' have successfully integrated the WordPress and WordPress Multi-User blogging platforms into Joomla!. Please visit us to see what these feature-rich components have to offer you. https://www.corephp.com/wordpress/wordpress-integration-for-joomla-1.5.html

Happy Blogging,

Michael Pignataro
VP of Operations
www.corephp.com